# Language with smart array allocation (heap or stack)

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, llvm, language-design

I am writing a small toy language/compiler for (fun and) scientific applications. Core design principles are simplicity and efficiency (some kind of "modern" Fortran if you will). The language would have built-in arrays, that would look something like that:

```
let x: Real[5] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0}

let n = get_runtime_value()
let y: Integer[100,n] = ...
```

In the above statement, the user does not explicitly states whether the array should be allocated on the stack or on the heap. If at all possible, I'd rather not expose that to the users (my reasoning is that most engineers don't know the difference, and should not have to care. They have other problems to worry about.).

Technically, I could write something like:

```
if (some input parameter cannot be known at compile time)
  allocate on the heap
else  # candidate for the stack
  if (the array is not returned by the function && the allocated size is smaller than some threshold)
     allocate on the stack
  else
     allocate on the heap
```

However, this design scares me for a few reasons:

1. Added complexity, longer compilation times?
2. In C++, the compiler can perform RVO and return a value on the stack directly. I guess I could make the algorithm more complex to detect such cases, but this will make the whole thing more complex/buggy/slow to compile.
3. A slight change in array size could cause the switch from stack to heap. That could be confusing for the user. Defining this threshold would also require some care.
4. I need to check that some reference to that array is not being returned either (as well as references of references, etc.). I imagine that could be expensive to track down.

Note that I do not want to expose pointers or references in my language. Arrays will always be passed by reference under the hood.

Is there a neat way in the literature to solve this problem? Has it been done before in an existing language? All the languages I know require the user to specify where they want their data: Fortran has `::allocatable`, C++ has `std::vector` and `std::array`, etc. I could also do something like llvm's `SmallVector` and always allocate a few elements on the stack before moving to the heap. Does my approach make any sense at all? I am using this project to learn more about compilers and language design. Is there something I should be watchful for?

Comment: Objects "on the stack" get automatically destroyed when the function that creates them returns, by definition. No exceptions. How were you proposing, in your language's C++ implementation, to guarantee that your language's objects will not be needed any more after whatever the C++ function, that creates them, returns?

Comment: I had in mind something similar to RVO in C++. However, I would need to go one step further and also make sure that the object on the stack being returned is not being returned by the caller. Else, the caller of the caller will end up with a dangling pointer.

Comment: Does your language have pointers/references? That is, is it possible that you pass a reference/pointer to an array as an argument to a function and then that function stores the reference/pointer in a variable?

Comment: The default answer is yes: people can create references of existing variables. However, if that becomes too problematic, it might not be so terrible to remove such references from the language (apart from function arguments). It would definitely simplify the analysis for stack/heap allocation.

Comment: @Touloudou I was asking because in that case you wouldn't just have to worry about returning the array, but also about a reference to the array being passed to another function, which stores it in a variable (meaning the reference could outlive the function that created the array).

Comment: If it's a toy language, just allocate from the heap for now. This is an opinion based question and, clearly, my comment is as well.

Answer (score 0):

The option is really up to you, but if I were you, I would let the user choose whether to allocate on the heap or stack. If not, it will most likely get very confusing for you, and the user. If you still want to implement the feature, I have some tips.

- Instead of checking if things cannot be known at compile-time, check what can be known at compile-time-- it will simplify things.
- Make everything defined on the heap or stack by default-- this will make it easier to handle situations where you need to switch from stack to heap (or vice versa) (it's easier because suppose when `append` is called you can switch to heap).

In conclusion, I recommend you let the user be explicit about declaring an array on the stack or heap.